# How to compute a funds TER?

Tags: stocks, investing, trading, etf

I’m getting started with investing and will be starting with ETFs. When searching for how to pick an ETF, a common term comes up: TER.

As I understand it, the formula is total fund cost divided by its total net assets. The latter is easy to find for a fund, but I am unsure how to derive the former.

Could somebody demonstrate how to arrive at this for say, SPY or SLYG?

I’m using Fidelity which has no commissions for these ETFs, so I am moving on to other metrics for determining which to invest in.

Comment: Why compute TER when they tell you the expense ratio (which ISTM what you *should* care about)?

Comment: What is ISTM? I know they show Net Expense Ratio which for SLYG is 0.15% and the lower the percentage the better, I was just curious if that was TER and/or how to calculate it.

Comment: https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/ISTM It Seems To Me

Answer (score 1):

The total expense ratio, or TER, is the number you want. This is defined as the fund's **annual** running costs. You usually can't calculate this yourself because you don't have all the variables (i.e. costs for management, infrastructure, compliance etc. - can greatly vary for the same underlying index across different funds/managers). This is exactly why the fund manager is obligated to tell you the TER of its funds in a document called KIID.

Comment: Why does this matter more than the expense ratio?

Comment: This is the expense ratio. There is only one term here. It's abbreviated TER. Colloquially, people call it 'expense ratio' or 'running costs'. All refer to the same thing.

Comment: Doesn't every MF and ETF publish it?  Vanguard, Fidelity and Schwab (the ones I have experience with) sure make it easy to find.

Comment: Yes, every serious fund manager publishes their funds' TER. No, investors can't really calculate that with public data. Therefore, OP's question is moot and now OP and all future readers hopefully know why.

Comment: @RonJohn I’m using Fidelity’s ETF screener and while net expense ratio is on the front page of each, a blinking arrow to the document outlining the TER isn’t present. I have to do more navigating to find it, which I still have not found the document mentioned on the ETFs page.

Comment: @pstatix but **why do you need** the TER instead of the NER?

Comment: @RonJohn no reason, learning about where it all comes from